# How can i send email from Yii

Tags: email, yii

Here is my code in controller

```
public function actionSendemail()
{
    $model = new EmailForm();
    if(isset($_POST['EmailForm']))
    { 
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EmailForm'];
        if($model->validate()){
                        $body = $_POST['User']['firstname'].$_POST['User']['lastname'].
                                $_POST['User']['$contactno'].$_POST['User']['body'];
                        $message = new YiiMailMessage;
                        $params = array('myMail'=>$body);
                        $message->subject    = $_POST['User']['subject'];
                        $message->setBody($params, 'text/html');                
                        $message->addTo('test@gmail.com');
                        $message->from = $_POST['User']['email'];
                        Yii::app()->mail->send($message);      
                    }
    }
            $list = TblPage::model()->findByPk(6);                  
            $this->render('contactview', array('list'=>$list, 'model'=>$model));              
}
```

But shows error:

include(YiiMailMessage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How to send email?

Comment: Try Siwftmailer :  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded and included in extension/yii-mail/YiiMail, then this can be placed in your application configuration.

```
'mail' => array(
    'class' => 'ext.yii-mail.YiiMail',
    'transportType' => 'smtp',
    'transportOptions' => array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'XXXX@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'XXXX',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption'=>'tls',
    ),
    'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
    'logging' => true,
    'dryRun' => false
),
```